# Jquery Progress Bar After Submit Stays On Page GOTO POST page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

Not sure if im explaining this correct i have a Form with a submit button i have to problems

1: If on submit i disable the submit button the Jquery never finishes not sure why.
2: Without the progress bar after post i would be direct to a page showing that the data has been saved to the SQL database with the progress bar its shows this information inside the same form page not sure how to make that work the other way with the progress bar.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
//Add
if ($action == 'Add') {

echo '<p align="center" class="mainpagefontadminheader">ESE Web Site Projects Administration - Add Projects - ' . $_POST['table'] . '</p>
<br>
<form action="adminese_work.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form" id="form">
<input type="hidden" name="table" value="' . $_POST['table'] . '"/>
  <hr width="600">
  <p class="mainpagefontadmin">Project Name: <input type="text" name="name" id="name" size="32" class="formelements"/></p>
  <hr width="600">
  <p class="mainpagefontadmin">Project Location: <input type="text" name="location" id="location" size="30" class="formelements"/></p>
  <hr width="600">
  <p class="mainpagefontadmin">Project Verbage: <textarea name="verbage" id="verbage" cols="45" rows="5" class="formelements"></textarea>  </p>
  <hr width="600">
  <p class="mainpagefontadmin">Project Main Photo: <input type="file" name="mainphoto" id="mainphoto" class="mainpagefontadmin"/><br />Please make sure your pixels are:(890x350)</p>
  <hr width="600">
  <p class="mainpagefontadmin">Project Thumbnails: <input type="button" onclick="addInput()" name="add" value="Add Upload Field" class="formelements"/> Click to Add More Upload Fields.</p>
  <div id="images">

  </div>
  <hr width="600">
  <span class="mainpagefontadmin">Maximum Post Size: 50 Megabytes.</span>
    <div class="progress">
        <div class="bar"></div >
        <div class="percent">0%</div >
    </div>
    <div id="status"></div>
  <hr width="600">
  <br>
  <table width="0" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="submit" name="Save" id="button" value="Save"></td>
    <td><input type="submit" name="Cancel" id="button" value="Cancel"></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
</form>
<script src="java/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="java/jquery.form.js"></script>
<script>
(function() {
var bar = $(\'.bar\');
var percent = $(\'.percent\');
var status = $(\'#status\');

$(\'form\').ajaxForm({
    beforeSend: function() {
        status.empty();
        var percentVal = \'0%\';
        bar.width(percentVal)
        percent.html(percentVal);
    },
    uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
        var percentVal = percentComplete + \'%\';
        bar.width(percentVal)
        percent.html(percentVal);
    },
    complete: function(xhr) {
     bar.width("100%");
    percent.html("100%");
     status.html(xhr.responseText);
    }
}); 

})();       
</script>';
}
```

The Save button calls
          if ($action == 'Save') {}

The info should be showing up in another page not the same page above

hope that makes sense.

Thanks

Comment: You need to fiddle this.

Comment: Sorry new to Jquery what do i do to fiddle it?